# Adding my dataframe to imported dataset (python)

Tags: python

I am studying a course from Udemy in imbalanced data.
I uploaded this data set:

```
from imblearn.datasets import fetch_datasets
```

Then choose one dataframe from the list, for example:

```
datasets_ls = [
    'thyroid_sick',
]
```

And for the dataset try different models:

```
for dataset in datasets_ls:
    
    # start a new dictionary per dataset
    results_dict[dataset] = {}
    shapes_dict[dataset] = {}
    
    print(dataset)
    
    # load dataset
    data = fetch_datasets()[dataset]
    
    # separate train and test
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
        data.data,  
        data.target, 
        test_size=0.3,
        random_state=0,
    )
    
    # as many undersampling techniques use KNN
    # we put the variables in the same scale
    scaler = MinMaxScaler().fit(X_train)
    X_train = scaler.transform(X_train)
    X_test = scaler.transform(X_test)
        
        
    # train a model on the original data without under-sampling
    # and determine model performance
    roc = run_randomForests(X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test)
    
    # store results
    results_dict[dataset]['full_data'] = roc
    shapes_dict[dataset]['full_data'] = len(X_train)
    
    print()
    
    # now, we test the different under-samplers, 1 at a time
    for undersampler in undersampler_dict.keys():
        
        print(undersampler)
        
        # resample the train set only
        X_resampled, y_resampled = undersampler_dict[undersampler].fit_resample(X_train, y_train)
        
        # train model and evaluate performance
        
        # Note the performance returned is using the
        # test set, which was not under-sampled
        
        roc = run_randomForests(X_resampled, X_test, y_resampled, y_test)
        
        # store results
        results_dict[dataset][undersampler] = roc
        shapes_dict[dataset][undersampler] = len(X_resampled)
        print()
        
    print()
```

My question is, how do I add my own datasets to this imported dataset?
I am a bit new to python so I appreciate your help.